# Reorder Ranked rows

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Recently i needed to implement a way to allow for Table Records to be Ranked.

Initially i deployed an Update statement to seed the ranks:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        t.id,
        Rank() Over (
            Partition by t.field2
            Order by t.id
        ) as [Rank],
        t.index,
        t.field2,
        t.field3 ,
        t.field4
    from dbo.Table t
    where t.field2 = @fldValue
) Update cte 
set index = [Rank]
```

But now i need to be able to have the end-user re-order the ranks.  Any suggestions on how to allow an end-user to take Rank value `92` to Rank value `15` and have everything be re-ranked appropriately.

I had thought about doing this via cursor but am trying to do this via `Set based operation`.

My first goto was to do a `Procedural based operation` but need to get more inline with `Set based operation`.

#### Table Schema

Table:

- id bigint
- field2 int
- field3 int ---> This field will be the key pivoting column for ranking
- field4 int

Data:

```
     id      field2      field3      field4
      1           0           1           1
      2           0           1           1
      3           0           1           1
      4           0           1           2
      5           0           1           2
      6           0           1           1
      7           0           1           1
      8           0           1           1
      9           0           1           1
     10           0           1           2
     11           0           1           2
     12           0           1           1
     13           0           1           1
     14           0           1           1
     15           0           1           2
     16           0           1           1
     17           0           1           2
     18           0           1           2
     19           0           1           1
```

Comment: Can you provide the test data and desired result.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan there ya go

Comment: Why not to use the same Update statement but limit it to records currently having Rank between 15 and 92 using WHERE clause or some of that kind? Records with Rank values below 15 and above 92 not change.

Comment: Got the implementation, just havent posted it yet.